# using both Visual Studio Team Services and Codeplex for repository

Tags: tfs, open-source, azure-devops, codeplex

I started a utilities project in Visual Studio Team Services where you could have multiple developers on a project, but ended up not needing the extra developers, but still liked the Visual Studio Team Services interfaces. I wanted to be able to share some of the projects I do to people that read my blog, but found out after I was using it for a while that I could not give access to the public (or at least I couldn't find away). I know Codeplex allows you to do this since it is specifically for open source projects.

Is there any way to keep the Visual Studio Team Services and the TFS on Codeplex in sync so I can work from one source control primarily? or even better, is there a way to publicly share by URL stuff you work on Visual Studio Team Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a way to share any Team Services content publicly.

However, if you use Git as your VCS in Team Services you can easily add two Origins and push to both with "git push -all".

If your codeplex repo is also git you can easily share.

Comment: Awesome Thank you very much. You wouldn't by any  chance know if it easy to convert a project from TFS to GIT or if I should just create a new project?

Comment: You need to create a new Team Project.